# Python setup.py for unusual folder structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, setup.py, python-wheel

I would like to craft a setup.py for a package with an unusual folder structure.

The usual structure is

```
topfolder (e.g. git folder name)
 - setup.py
 - pkgname/
  - __init__.py
  - file1.py
  - folder1/
    - file2.py
```

The usual setup.py would be

```
from setuptools import setup
PACKAGES = ["pkgname",]
setup(packages=PACKAGES)
```

Upon installation the folder name pkgname/ is copied into miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/. As a user you can import this as

```
import pkgname
import pkgname.folder1
import pkgname.folder1.file2
import pkgname.file1
etc...
```

Now, for reasons that don't matter I can't/am not allowed to change the unusual folder structure. Instead, I'm stuck with this:

```
topfolder (which is also the pkgname)
 - __init__.py
 - file1.py
 - folder1/
  - file2.py
```

So as you can see, setup.py doesn't exist, the top folder is named after the package name, and everything that should be under pkgname/ is one level down.

I have actually managed to craft a setup.py that installs this. Just call the package ".":

```
from setuptools import setup
PACKAGES = [".",]
setup(packages=PACKAGES)
```

Now the problem is that upon installation the contents of topfolder get dumped directly into miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ (as opposed to a folder being created there and the contents dumped into that folder). As a consequence, as a user I have to import as:

```
import folder1
import folder1.file2
import file1
```

I.e. because of how the installation is working, I lost the namespace.

Question: how do I craft a setup.py such that the unusual folder structure can be installed and used in the usual way?

Comment: Is there any reason why you do not just place the ``setup.py`` one folder up?

Comment: That is "outside". Specifically, "topfolder" is a git repo. There is no up.